# ITK: Can't find ITKCommon-x.xx.dll when executing HelloWorld Example

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, itk

i successfully built ITK 4.13 (as 'Release') on Windows 10 with the latest Visual Studio version (Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64 compiler). Then i tried to built the `ITKHelloWorld` example using the following `CMakeLists.txt` (as shown in the example by ITK):

```
#CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(HelloWorld)
find_package(ITK REQUIRED)
include(${ITK_USE_FILE})
add_executable(HelloWorld HelloWorld.cxx)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

Built runs without errors or warnings. Running the generated `HelloWorld.exe` file result in an `ITKCommon-4.13.dll not found` error.

The `ITKCommon-4.13.dll` was built by ITK, thus, i think i have to change something in the CMakeList file, but don't know what.

Any guess or solution?

**Edit:** The `include(${ITK_USE_FILE})` expression in `CMakeLists` searches for `UseITK.cmake`, but this file is located in the source of ITK not in the build folder. Could this be a source of the error?

**Edit2:** Running a VTK Example also shows errors caused by not finding required `.dll`s.

Comment: You could compile ITK as static libraries, and not have to worry about DLLs or path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your project. Windows can use dll libraries on runtime only if they are in PATH location. So there are two options: either you add `bin/Release` directory of ITK library to Windows's PATH system variable (the directory that contains all the ddls), or you just copy all the dlls from that directory to the one that contains your new application.

Precisely, you don't need to copy all the dlls, you can check by e.g. Dependency Walker, which ones are really needed.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just wondering, why there is no option to add used shared libraries dynamically to the PATH (maybe just temporary) to avoid duplicate files on the file system.
On the other hand: The executable itself should include paths to the libraries or not? Why do i need to add them to the path?

Comment: Ad 1. Actually, these is such option. You could have set the value of  `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to `c:\windows\system32` and then build also `INSTALL` project in Visual Studio. Then the dlls would have been copied to the directory. But in this case you cannot have various concurrent ITK libraries in the system. Ad 2. In Windows, an executable "doesn't have knowledge" where its dlls are located, OS is responsible for run-time linking. You can also do in `cmd`: `set PATH=c:\...ITK...\bin\Release;%PATH%` and then run the app. This will modify PATH only locally, for this session.

Comment: @norb Another option is to add the path temporary in Visual Studio. In solution explorer right click on your project and select last entry Properties. Under Configuration Management -> Debugging -> Environment add the path to your ITK install or development directory as follows: `PATH=<YOUR_ITK_INSTALL_DIR>;%PATH%`.

Comment: Thanks again! In the end I added the library directory to the Windows PATH and it works perfect.